# How to sort varchar string properly with numeric values on both ends?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, dynamic-pivot

I'm building a `Common Table Expression (CTE)` in `SQL Server 2008` to use in a `PIVOT` query.

I'm having difficulty sorting the output properly because there are numeric values that sandwich the string data in the middle. Is it possible to do this?

This is a quick and dirty example, the real query will span several years worth of values.

Example:

```
Declare @startdate as varchar(max);
Declare @enddate as varchar(max);
Set @startdate = cast((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())-1) as varchar(4))+'-12-01';
Set @enddate = cast((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())) as varchar(4))+'-03-15';

WITH DateRange(dt) AS
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @startdate) dt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,dt) dt FROM DateRange WHERE dt < CONVERT(datetime, @enddate)
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME((cast(DATEPART(yyyy, dt) as varchar(4)))+'-Week'+(cast(DATEPART(ww, dt) as varchar(2)))) FROM DateRange
```

Current Output:

```
,[2012-Week48]
,[2012-Week49]
,[2012-Week50]
,[2012-Week51]
,[2012-Week52]
,[2012-Week53]
,[2013-Week1]
,[2013-Week10]
,[2013-Week11]
,[2013-Week2]
,[2013-Week3]
,[2013-Week4]
,[2013-Week5]
,[2013-Week6]
,[2013-Week7]
,[2013-Week8]
,[2013-Week9]
```

Desired Output:

```
,[2012-Week48]
,[2012-Week49]
,[2012-Week50]
,[2012-Week51]
,[2012-Week52]
,[2012-Week53]
,[2013-Week1]
,[2013-Week2]
,[2013-Week3]
,[2013-Week4]
,[2013-Week5]
,[2013-Week6]
,[2013-Week7]
,[2013-Week8]
,[2013-Week9]
,[2013-Week10]
,[2013-Week11]
```

**EDIT**

Of course after I post the question my brain started working. I changed the `DATEADD` to add 1 week instead of 1 day and then took out the `DISTINCT` in the select and it worked.

```
DECLARE @startdate AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @enddate AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @startdate = CAST((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())-1) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-12-01';
SET @enddate = CAST((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-03-15';

WITH DateRange(dt) AS
    (
            SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @startdate) dt
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(ww,1,dt) dt FROM DateRange WHERE dt < CONVERT(datetime, @enddate)
    )
    SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME((CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, dt) AS VARCHAR(4)))+'-Week'+(CAST(DATEPART(ww, dt) AS VARCHAR(2)))) FROM DateRange
```

Comment: Looks like a bad approach.  You are starting with strings, casting them to datetimes, running a query, and then converting back to a string.  Why not start with datetimes, run your query, and output the formatted date, but order by the actual date?

Comment: Because the pivot table Im using stores actual dates, but in a modified julian format.  I need to create the pivot to total by week that will span over years.  This is only the first quarter of the overall solution, but it's what I need.  Im not overly concerned with performance as for this will run once a month and finishes in a reasonable amount of time.  There may be a better way to do it but this is what I have for a solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the `DATEADD` portion of the query and remove the `DISTINCT`.  Once changed the order sorted properly on it's own

```
DECLARE @startdate AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @enddate AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @startdate = CAST((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())-1) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-12-01';
SET @enddate = CAST((DATEPART(yyyy, GetDate())) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-03-15';

WITH DateRange(dt) AS
    (
            SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @startdate) dt
            UNION ALL
            SELECT DATEADD(ww,1,dt) dt FROM DateRange WHERE dt < CONVERT(datetime, @enddate)
    )
    SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME((CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, dt) AS VARCHAR(4)))+'-Week'+(CAST(DATEPART(ww, dt) AS VARCHAR(2)))) FROM DateRange
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the sample SQL code (that site is blacklisted where I am).

Here is a trick for sorting that data in the proper order is to use the length first and then the values:

```
select col
from t
order by left(col, 6), len(col), col;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is the years could be different but have the same length.  I like the concept though.

Comment: @sgeddes . . . Duh.  You are right.  This originally put all the week1's together regardless of year.  I fixed that by just taking the first 6 characters of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to sort on two temporary columns (year in smallint and week in tinyint to save space … or directly using the datepart integer if space is not a problem to you and you prefer fast run) along with the use of "order by year, week" ?

If you store dates using a more suitable type (what I suggest), it would then become :

```
WITH [Define the CTE expression name and column list]
AS
  (
    SELECT CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, dt) as smallint(4)) year, cast(DATEPART(ww, dt) as tinyint(2)) week, [your columns here]
    FROM DateRange WHERE dt < @enddate
  )
[Define the outer query referencing the CTE name]
ORDER BY year, week;
GO
```

Also, please note that string operations will slow your queries so avoid them when possible !

Answer (score 0):

I like Gordon's answer, but if you were hell-bent on text manipulation in your order by:

```
ORDER BY     CAST(REPLACE(LEFT('[2012-Week48]',5),'[','')AS INT)
            ,CAST(REPLACE(RIGHT('[2012-Week48]',CHARINDEX('Week','[2012-Week48]')-4),']','') AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option converting the beginning and ending parts of the column to integer.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(yourcolumn,1,4) as int), 
  CAST(SUBSTRING(yourcolumn,CHARINDEX('Week',yourcolumn)+4,len(yourcolumn)) as int)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7413/1)

This will work assuming the format of the data is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `dt` to generate the string, you should sort by using the date's parts:

```
WITH DateRange(dt) ...
SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAM...
ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy, dt), DATEPART(ww, dt)
```

Comment: It didnt like that because I wasn't selecting yyyy and ww in the SELECT and it contained a DISTINCT.  I did fix it though, posted above.